# React Native : Arrow function on production build not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I recently faced an issue with react native production build with android and ios. I have a `formik` form and `onsubmit` of that I have called an API with arrow function and handle that response. It was working fine in the simulator and debugging with the real device but when we create `apk` or `ipa` from it the function was not working, after 1 day of debugging it when I changed it to a normal javascript function it was working fine.

why is this happening?

Arrow Function Code (Was Not Working)

```
 const forget = values => {
    Alert.alert('third')
    const url = 'forgetpassword';
    post(url, values).then(data => handleForgetResponse(data));
  };
```

Normal function Code (Working)

```
  function forget (values){
    Alert.alert('third')
    const url = 'forgetpassword';
    post(url, values).then(data => handleForgetResponse(data));
 }
```

Component Code

```
 <Formik
            initialValues={{
              email: '',
            }}
            innerRef={formRef}
            onSubmit={(values, {setSubmitting}) => {
              Alert.alert('first')
              forget(values);
              Alert.alert('second')
            }}
            validate={validateForget}>
            {props => (
              <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <View style={styles.forgetpassword}>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontSize: an(20),
                      fontWeight: '700',
                      marginVertical: hp(1),
                    }}>
                    {'Forgot Password'}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={{fontWeight: '200'}}>
                    {'Please enter your email address or mobile'}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={{fontWeight: '200'}}>
                    {'number to receive a verification code.'}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <RenderTextInput
                  text={'Registered Email OR Mobile Number'}
                  style={{width: '90%', marginHorizontal: hp(2)}}
                  value={props.values.email}
                  autoCapitalize={'none'}
                  autoCapitalize={'words'}
                  onChangeText={props.handleChange('email')}
                  error={props.touched.email && props.errors.email}
                  blur={() => props.setFieldTouched('email', true)}
                  returnKeyType="next"
                  onSubmitEditing={() =>
                    passwordRef?.current?.focus()
                  }></RenderTextInput>

                <RenderButton
                  text={'Submit'}
                  textStyle={{color: 'white'}}
                  style={{
                    marginVertical: hp(2),
                    marginHorizontal: hp(2),
                    height: hp(7),
                    width: '90%',
                  }}
                  onPress={props.handleSubmit}></RenderButton>
              </View>
            )}
          </Formik>
```

Function

```
  // const forget = values => {
  //   Alert.alert('third')
  //   const url = 'forgetpassword';
  //   post(url, values).then(data => handleForgetResponse(data));
  // };

  function forget (values){
    Alert.alert('third')
    const url = 'forgetpassword';
    post(url, values).then(data => handleForgetResponse(data));
  }

  const handleForgetResponse = data => {
    Alert.alert('fourth')
    ShowToast(data.message, data.status);
    if (data.status == 1) {
      navigation.navigate('Verification', {
        email: data.email,
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: did you use these handler functions on a class-based component?

Comment: NO, on functional component

Comment: please share the full code snippet where do you define and used in

Comment: please share the code, was the function invoked, add a console log in the funciton.

Comment: The problem is not about function defining with an arrow function, simply you can check this, you are using another arrow function in `then` method. so the problem is not with the arrow function. but your implementation might cause the issue.

Comment: question code updated

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your implementation with two types of functions and ignoring the `hoisting` concept in Javascript.

###### A quick fix:

```
  function forget (values){
    Alert.alert('third')
    const url = 'forgetpassword';
    post(url, values).then(data => handleForgetResponse(data));
  }

  function handleForgetResponse (data) {
    Alert.alert('fourth')
    ShowToast(data.message, data.status);
    if (data.status == 1) {
      navigation.navigate('Verification', {
        email: data.email,
      });
    }
  };
```

##### Explanation:

You can invoke a regular function before defining it, but you can't do the same with the arrow function. let's consider this example:

```
regularFn()  // work fine!
arrowFn()    // ---> Cannot access 'arrowFn' before initialization

function regularFn () {
  console.log("regular funciton called")
}

const arrowFn = () => {
  console.log("arrow funciton called")
}
```

the `regularFn()` will work, but the `arrowFn()` will cause error.

Back to your case, you are using an arrow function in the `forget` function before defining it. so you can define it before `forget` function or use the regular function to solve the issue.

Comment: Your point about hoisting is right. But this is not the issue in my case. The same code with the arrow function is working in another component also. for example, in login, I have the same code. with one extra input, it works fine in the login component

Comment: did you try to change the implementaion? what is the result? which part of your code snippet wasn't working? are the alerts invoked? @swapnilgautam

Comment: alert did work with normal function but not with the arrow function, but same code was working on login component with arrow function

Comment: so did you change the implementaion and consider the hoisting? @swapnilgautam